# Recursively match and remove file extentions in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server

Tags: fedora, file-rename

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server. I have files

file1.encrypted.decrypted, 
myfile.encrypted.decrypted, demo.encrypted.decrypted.

I want to write a command such that in output both extentions are removed.

Output = 
file1,
myfile,
demo

I tried

```
rename 's/\.encrypted\.decrypted//' *.encrypted.decrypted
```

But it does not produce the desired result (Please note this exact command works on ubuntu 18)

I am not sure why rename `'s/\.encrypted\.decrypted//' *.encrypted.decrypted` is not working in my case ?

I am using
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.4 (Maipo) ID_LIKE="fedora"

Comment: There are two (incompatible) programs, both called `rename`.

Comment: I did not understand please elaborate

Comment: $ whereis rename
rename: /usr/bin/rename /usr/share/man/man1/rename.1.gz I got these should I remove one of them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked: `rename .encrypted.decrypted "" *`